# Good way to create a dynamic listview with data from SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I want to program simple organizer with Notes.
I have a SQLite database with some data as shown below:

```
_id | time | date | text
 1  | 9:45 | 12.01| blabla
 2  | 21:01| 13.01| albalb
 ...| ...  | ...  | ...
```

Also I have a class `Note`:

```
public class Note {
    private int id;
    private String time;
    private String date;
    private String text;
    public Note(final int id, final String time, final String date, final String text){
        setId(id);
        setTime(time);
        setDate(date);
        setText(text);
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public String getTime(){
        return time;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    void setId(final int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    void setTime(final String time){
        this.time = time;
    }
    void setDate(final String date){
        this.date = date;
    }
    void setText(final String text){
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

And NotesManager:

```
public class NotesManager {
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "NotesListTable";
    private static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

    private final SQLiteDatabase db;
    public NotesManager(SQLiteDatabase db){
        this.db = db;
    }
    public void save(final ContentValues cv){
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }
    public void delete(final int id){
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null);
    }
    public Note getNoteById(final int id){
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return new Note(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIME)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT)));
    }
    public Cursor getAllDataFromDB(){
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    public String[] getKeysArray(){
        return new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_TIME, KEY_DATE, KEY_TEXT};
    }
}
```

I have a fragment with ListView:
It has been generated by Android Studio, nut I made some changes, added SimpleCursorAdapter

```
public class NotesListFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private int mSectionNumber = 0;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private AbsListView mListView;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    private Cursor cursor;
    ImageButton deleteButton;
    NotesManager notesManager = new NotesManager(OrganizerApp.db);

    public static NoesListFragment newInstance(int param1) {
        NoesListFragment fragment = new NotesListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public NotesListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mSectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        }
        cursor = NotesManager.getAllDataFromDB();
        //TODO:  startManagingCursor(cursor)

        //mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<NotesListContent.NotesItem>(getActivity(),
        //        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, NotesListContent.ITEMS);
        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.note_list_rowlayout,
                cursor,
                notesManager.getKeysArray(),
                new int[]{R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item1,
                        R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item2,
                        R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item3,
                        R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item4 });
        deleteButton = (ImageButton) getView().
                findViewById(R.id.note_list_rowlayout_deleteButton);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(onClickDeleteButton);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        //((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mSectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(mSectionNumber);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (null != mListener) {
            // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
            // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
           // mListener.onFragmentInteraction(NotesListContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
        }
    }

    public void setEmptyText(CharSequence emptyText) { // If list is empty.
        View emptyView = mListView.getEmptyView();

        if (emptyView instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) emptyView).setText(emptyText);
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickDeleteButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };

}
```

Android studio also generated NotesListContent.java:

```
public class NotesListContent {

    public static List<Note> ITEMS = new ArrayList<Note>();

    //public static Map<String, Note> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, Note>();

    private static void addItem(Note item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        //ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }



    /**
     * A dummy item representing a piece of content.

    public static class NoteItem {
        public String id;
        public String content;

        public NoteItem(String id, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }*/
}
```

So my solution works, but I think that it is bad.

1. For what I need a NotesListContent.java? How can I use it?
2. How can I use ListView without deprecated simpleCursorAdapter?
3. How to delete and add items without refresh **all** ListView?
4. Especially this code seems to be very unconvenient:

   scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                   R.layout.note_list_rowlayout,
                   cursor,
                   notesManager.getKeysArray(),
                   new int[]{R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item1,
                           R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item2,
                           R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item3,
                           R.id.note_list_rowlayout_item4 });

Comment: unconvenient? What is unconvenient in that constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I've done notes manager of my own so I'll try to answer Your questions.

> For what I need a NotesListContent.java? How can I use it?

This is somewhat [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern, separation of data from view. Try to think about it as an entity, or better as a single note entry description.

> How can I use ListView without deprecated simpleCursorAdapter?

a) since when is [simpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) depreciated? Only one of it's constructor is.
b) You can use second constructor, or extend some adapter class (for example ArrayAdapter) Yourself

> How to delete and add items without refresh all ListView?

You add data to Your dataAdapter, then set dataAdapter as an adapter for ListView (listview.setAdapter(adapter)).
If You do not call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() listview's view will not be updated.

> Especially this code seems to be very unconvenient (...)

What's so wrong about it? But if so, feel free to use sth like this:

```
String[] columns = new String[] {  // The desired columns to be bound
        "timestamp",
        "title",
        "content",
};

// the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
int[] map_to = new int[] {
        R.id.timestamp,
        R.id.title,
        R.id.content,
};

dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.some_xml_here,
        db.getAllItems(),
        columns,
        map_to,
        0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
May be I should not to use way "Database -> temporary Cursor -> ListView" and should do something like "Database -> temporary Cursor -> List of Notes (List<Note> in NotesListContent.java) -> ListView"? Because so I will have a list of notes which is easy to work with. If that better than how can I create List<Note>? And how can I modify ArrayAdapter to put several fiels to each row?

Android recommends the use of CursorAdapet as I remembered.

Comment: Well this depends, how tightly is Your whole application written - but in general yes it is preferred to use ArrayList<Note>. To create ArrayList<Note> You'd have to create CustomCursorAdapter and extend base adapter, assuming You want it to be populated from DB same way as simpleCursorAdapter, otherwise just List<Note> list = new ArrayList<Note>() . You can find multiple examples on how to do that, provide implementation of getView() is sufficient, it's short, but can be adjusted to Your needs